# How to align text input and label when validation appears

Tags: php, html, css

Got a form table below which contains form elements such as text inputs and validation messages:

```
$error_user = (!empty($errors['user']))?$errors['user']:"";
$error_email = (!empty($errors['email']))?$errors['email']:"";  

            echo "<form action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$user'/><br/>".$error_user."</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'/><br/>".$error_email."</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset Password' /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>";
```

Now I am displaying each validation message below the relevant text inputs but the problem is the allignment. If I display the message underneath the text input as I am doing now, then the text input moves up a little bit to occupy the space below for the validation message, meaning the text input is not leveled with its label e.g `Email` text input not aligned with this label when validation appears.

My question is that how can I get the label and text inputs to stay align with each other when the validation message appears underneath

Comment: Why don't you create a new tr for each validation messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this:

```
echo "<form action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign='top'>Username</td>
        <td valign='top'><input type='text' name='user' value='$user'/><br/>Username Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign='top'>Email</td>
        <td valign='top'><input type='text' name='email' value='$email'/><br/>Email Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset Password' /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";
```

You should get the look you want. The reason the message distorts the row is because it is enlarging one cell so the cell with the labels in are being aligned vertically in the middle. Notice the `valign:top`? That will push everything to the top of the cell so everything in the row on the first line, will be in line.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upXYe/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="vertical-align: top"` to all `TD` tags. You may also need to add a little padding to the label cells, to align them properly with the content in the input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

create another `<td>` element for displaying error message like this edit

```
<tr>
 <td>Username</td>
 <td><input type='text' name='user' value='$user'/></td>
 <td>".$error_user."</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: He wants to show validation messages beneath the input tags, not in front of them

Answer (score 0):

also, besides everything mentioned, and if it doesn't screw you anything else, i would try adding a space in the empty td's like this:

```
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
```

it will make things equally distributed